# Asymptotic recovery of sparse coefficient vector with lasso

Tags: regression, lasso, asymptotics

Given $\beta^* \in \mathbb{R}^d$, suppose $X_n \sim N(\mathbf{0}, I_d)$ are iid and $Y_n = X_n\beta^* + \epsilon_n$, where $\epsilon_n \sim N(0, 1)$ and are iid.

Let $\hat{\beta}_n$ be the solution to the problem
\begin{align*}
&\text{minimize } ||Y_n -X_n\beta||_2^2 \\
&\text{subject to }  ||\beta||_1 \leq t
\end{align*}
Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the indices such that $\beta^*_j = 0$. Let $I_n = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if $\hat{\beta}_{nj} = 0$ for all $j \in \mathcal{J}$} \\
0 \text{ else}\end{cases} $

I'm interested in the conditions for which $P(I_n = 1) \rightarrow 1$. For example, does this happen if we set $t = ||\beta^*||_1$? Of course, if we set $t = 0$, then this holds trivially. Do there exist other $t$'s that work, and which one would be optimal? (Not sure how exactly to quantify this). If there aren't any other $t$'s that work, are there other distributions we could set for $X_n$ so that other $t$'s exist?

Edit: Let's also assume the nonzero entries of $\beta^*$ are very large.

Comment: A relevant jargon term is "sparsistency", meaning that the set ${\cal J}$ is recovered asymptotically.  Larry Wasserman's course notes on statistical machine learning address it nicely: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/LinearRegression.pdf and https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/sparsity.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. I notice that he does not put a subscript $n$ on $X$. Does that mean that $X$ is fixed?

Comment: Also, if we replace the $X$ in his article with $X_n$ from my question, it seems like those conditions are satisfied for all $n$, at least with high probability.